# VSCode - Text highlight in "find" box

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently installed VSCode on a new machine, but found something odd about highlighted text in the "find" box.

How would one change the highlight color in this field in VS Code?

[image: Bad highlight color in find box]

Comment: you have to look in the theme colors and customize them in your settings, or ask the theme designer to update them to make it readable

Comment: The answer is here: stackoverflow.com/a/67098379/836330 And so this is a duplicate, unfortunately that answer hasn't been upvoted or accepted, sigh ..  So I'll post the same answer here and close the other if accepted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly, it is just

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "selection.background": "#ff0000",
}
```

Stumbled on it at [theme base colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#base-colors):

> `selection.background`: Background color of text selections in the
> workbench (for input fields or text areas, does not apply to
> selections within the editor and the terminal).