# Vscode terminal change the find highlight color

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if someone knows how to get the vscode integrated terminal find highlight to pop out more on the page.

Here's what mine looks like currently:

[image: hard to see highlight]

It is tough to make out the gray on black highlight color.

This answer explains how to change the highlight color of text NOT in the integrated terminal
[VSCode - Text highlight in "find" box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67763977/vscode-text-highlight-in-find-box)

This answer explains how to change all the colors of the terminal:
[Color theme for VS Code integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307949/color-theme-for-vs-code-integrated-terminal)

Answer (score 19):

Figured it out!

Add this snippet to your JSON settings:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "terminal.selectionBackground": "#e26cffcb",
}
```

Now my terminal looks like:
[image: an easy to find highlight selection]

Yahoo!!

Answer (score 14):

For those who get here looking for how to change the **find match** colors in the terminal (the question and other answers are about the terminal selection color) here are the new `colorCustomizations` (see  [v1.66 re;ease notes: terminal find match colors](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_66.md#display-all-find-matches)

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {

    "terminal.findMatchBackground": "#ff0000",
    "terminal.findMatchBorder": "#ff0000",
    "terminal.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#ff0000",
    "terminal.findMatchHighlightBorder": "#ff0000",
    "terminalOverviewRuler.findMatchForeground": "#ff0000"
  }
```